# Minimum number of vertices of a triangulation of the Mobius Strip

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

#### Mobius Strip and Homology Groups

I've been reading Croom, Basic concepts of Algebraic Topology.
I have a question.

What is the minimum number of vertices in a triangulation of Mobius strip?
Theorem 2.8 says:

$\alpha_0 \geq \frac{1}{2} (7+ \sqrt{49 - 24 \chi(M)})$

I know that Homology Groups of the strip is:
$H_2(M) = {0}$, $H_1(M) = \mathbb{Z}$, $H_0(M) = \mathbb{Z}$. So the sum for the 2-manifold is:

$\chi(M) = \sum_{p=0}^{p=2} R_p(M) = + 1 - 1 + 0 = 0$ where $R_p(M)$ is the Betti number which is defined as the rank of the free part in the decomposition of the homology group for a particular p.

Substituting back into 2.8 tell me I need at least 7 vertices. My confusion is, throughout the book it uses the following triangulation which has only 6 vertices:

[image: mobius strip triangluation]

So my conclusion is, either $\chi(M)$ is 1 not 0 in order to obey 2.8 or the above triangulation is false. Maybe 2.8 is not applicable to non-orientable n-manifolds?

Thanks in advance.

evrim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are referring to (Theorem 2.8) holds for $n-$pseudomanifolds, while the Mobius strip has a boundary  (look at Exercise 24 for the definition of $n-$pseudomanifold with boundary). The point is that the 1-simplices of the boundary are a face of just one 2-simplex (in contrast with point (b) of the definition of $n-$pseudomanifold).

Moreover in exercise 7 there is an example of triangulation of the cylinder that is the analogue of the one you are using for the Mobius strip.

Comment: Thank you @Dario, this is correct. Now i'm trying to understand the sets of the structures that I should be familiar with. Theorem 2.11 tells me that there are non-orientable n-pseudomanifolds. Therefore $n-pseudomanifols = {non-orientables} \cup {orientables}$. As you've said, cylinder is not a 2-pseudomanifold since a top/bottom line is just a face of a single 2-simplex. Interestingly, it is orientable I guess. On the other hand, mobius strip is non-orientable and not a 2-pseudomanifold. So as far I undestand, there are structures in every possibility of this classification.